Selective aggregate function in Postgres
We have a Postgres table that looks like below. How to create a three column one row view that shows summary of the table:

Maximum of all values
Maximum of all values with category 1
Maximum of all values with category 2




category
value




1
1


2
2


1
3


2
4




You could use conditional aggregation...
select 
 max(value) as max_all, 
 max(case when category = 1 then value end) as max_cat1, 
 max(case when category = 2 then value end) as max_cat2
From 
 table1




max_all
max_cat1
max_cat2




4
3
4




Instead of a CASE, you can use FILTER(WHERE ?). See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

@FrankHeikens Do you think that's faster or what advantage do you expect?

It's standard SQL, 2003 I think, and makes your SQL easier to read. I never did any performance tests on this, no idea if it's faster. I would use it just because of readability, makes it easier to write, test and maintain.

I agree it's nice syntax and good to read, unfortunately, some RDBMS still don't provide it. Maybe this will be better in future releases.
